# JPQL - ManyToMany Self reference

Tags: java, sql, jpa, playframework, jpql

I'm having a problem to make a query with JPQL. I have one table with reference himself with Many to Many:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "item")
public class Item  extends BaseModel implements Serializable {
    @Column(name = "id")
    public INteger id;

    @ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
    public Set<Item> itemsRelated;

}
```

And I'm trying to make this query:

```
Select * from Item where  itemsRelated=null
```

or
    Select * from Item where  itemsRelated is null

But its throwled this Exception:

play.exceptions.JavaExecutionException: Error while executing query **from Item where  itemsRelated=null order by createDate desc**: Unknown column 'qualified' in 'where clause'
    at play.mvc.ActionInvoker.invoke(ActionInvoker.java:237)
    at Invocation.HTTP Request(Play!)

Can anyone help me?

UPDATE:

Java call:

```
Item.find(query.toString()+" order by createDate desc").fetch(page, itemsPerPage);
```

At this point "query" has " itemsRelated is null"

Answer (score 1):

`itemsRelated` is a collection and you have to check the size of the collection - don't expect it to be `null`. Try

```
select i from Item i where i.itemsRelated is empty
```

See http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17904_01/apirefs.1111/e13946/ejb3_langref.html#ejb3_langref_empty_comp

Edit: completed query with alias

Comment: Now error: itemsRelated is not mapped [from models.aquilesModels.entity.Item where itemsRelated IS NOT EMPTY order by createDate desc]

Answer (score 0):

I'm not a jpql expert, but the syntax `is null` and `is not null` should work.
Have you tried

```
Select * from Item where itemsRelated is null
```

http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17904_01/apirefs.1111/e13946/ejb3_langref.html#ejb3_langref_null

Comment: Can you post a java snippet with the select statement?

Answer (score 0):

Successful!

The soluction was to use INNER JOIN, lets se:

```
id NOT IN (SELECT DISTINCT(i.id) FROM Item i INNER JOIN i.itemsRelated ii)
```

the result is:

```
Select * from Item where id NOT IN (SELECT DISTINCT(i.id) FROM Item i INNER JOIN i.itemsRelated ii)
```

Thanks for everyone!